# Print is not working in orgchart

Tags: orgchart

I am currently using getorgchart plugin. When ı want to print the chart , ıt opens a blank page.

```
$("#people").getOrgChart("print");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the target document element (in your case *people*) inside something else. For example, nest it inside another div.

Example:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="people"></div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SdgTU/48/)