# GetOrgChart - Exporting to Image and PDF returns error and Blank

Tags: getorgchart

Everytime I tried exporting it to Image it gives me an error while exporting it to PDF returns blank page.

Here is my sample of GetOrgChart

http://mlm-ads-success.000webhostapp.com/kirk.html

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered before - [Print is not working in orgchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28457817/print-is-not-working-in-orgchart).

So you just need to add additional surrounding DIV like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="people"></div>
</div>
```

Then the chart will print e.g. the part that is in the web browser view. Usually for larger charts this means enabling and exporting to PNG will be better alternative.